# MS sql sub-grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using MS SQL 2012

Have a table with 3 columns that i care about

SubcategoryID (int)
Manufacturer (nvarchar)
Model (nvarchar)

I want to take the top 10 most popular manufacturers (those that have the most entries in the table) and then get the 10 most popular subcatagories for each of those 10 manufacturers 
and then get the top 5 most popular models in each of those subcategories.

So in the end, assuming there's enough data, i should have a maximum of 500 results:

top 10 manufacturer X top 10 subcategories X top 5 models

The closest i've gotten so far to doing this is this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*), SubcategoryID, Manufacturer from dbo.Product
WHERE ManufacturerID IN
(
SELECT TOP 10 Manufacturerid FROM dbo.Product
WHERE Manufacturer != '' AND Manufacturer != 'NOT SPECIFIED' AND Manufacturer IS NOT NULL AND ManufacturerID IS NOT null
AND Deleted = 0 AND StatusID = 1
GROUP BY Manufacturerid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
GROUP BY Manufacturer, dbo.Product.SubcategoryID
ORDER BY  Manufacturer, COUNT(*) desc
```

But that doesn't really work since it's giving me more then 10 records for each manufacturer - and i haven't tried getting the model yet

Appreciate any help in this, thanks

EDIT: i didn't explain this correctly - i want to get the top 10 most common manufacturers within each subcategory, not the top 10 most popular manufacturers as a whole.

In other words:

```
select top 10 manufacturers from product where subcategoryid = 123 group by manufacturer order by count(*) desc
```

But I'd want that for each subcategory in the table. And then the top 5 models within each Subcategory/Manufacturer

Comment: One question about your schema: could a SubCategoryID be shared among multiple manufacturers?

Comment: Yes, it could. There's a chance model could be the same across manufacturers and subcategories as well.

Comment: You might want to look at the CROSS APPLY operator, if it's available in SQL 2012: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are not limiting the model to the top 10 for each manufacturer.

See if this works...

```
SELECT Manufacturer, Model, SubCategoryID
FROM Product
WHERE Manufacturer IN (
        SELECT TOP 10 Manufacturer
        FROM Product
        GROUP BY Manufacturer
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC )
AND SubCategoryID IN (
        SELECT TOP 10 SubCategoryID
        FROM Product a
        WHERE a.Manufacturer = Product.Manufacturer
        GROUP BY SubCategoryID
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC )
AND Model IN (
        SELECT TOP 5 Model
        FROM Product a
        WHERE a.Manufacturer = Product.Manufacturer
        AND a.SubCategoryID = Product.SubCategoryID
        GROUP BY Model
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC )
```

Comment: I apologize - I didn't explain what i wanted correctly. I've edited the original question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks - i think this does what i want.

Comment: I had to put this on hold while I was working on something else and just came back to this. Unfortunately, the above query isn't exactly right. I should at most get 500 records return. 10 manufacturers x 10 sub categories x 5 models. In other words, for each manufacturer, there should be at most 50 records - the 10 most popular subcategories and then the 5 most popular models in each subcategory. I think just adding groupby manufacturer, model, subcategoryid should fix it.